# create graphic with multiple data-columns in different appearance in jmp

Tags: data-visualization, jmp

in jmp 11 on a mac I have data I want to plot nicely in a 2d-diagram. For the datapoints I made a regression to get a function for a smooth curve, now I want to plot the datapoints and the function in one graph.

However in the graphic-creating-window I can only select the appearance for all columns, i.e. either 'dots' (for the datapoints) or 'function' (for the smooth function). If I select 'dots', both datacolumns are represented as only dots, if I select 'function', only the smooth function is shown. But I want to see the datapoints as dots and the function as continous line. Is this possible in jmp?

Regards, Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using Graph Builder in JMP, it's possible to combine both the Points and the Formula elements. Use shift-click to turn them both on (or right-click in the graph and choose Add...). After turning both on, you'll see dots for both; however, that you can turn off the dots for the formula column by opening the Variables section of the Points properties on the left of the graph (with the "..." button) and unchecking the formula column:

[image]

BTW, JMP has a [community forum](https://community.jmp.com/welcome) for JMP-specific questions and discussion.